# What users are accessing and downloading in general in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Can I track what users are accessing and downloading in Azure DevOps? I know about the **Audit log**, however can the **Usage tab** to the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot check who accessed or downloaded in general in Azure DevOps, we could only check the changes that occur throughout an Azure DevOps organization in the Auditing page. Since these operations have not changed Azure DevOps, we could not get the logs.

In addition, this API shows a list of all [audit events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/audit/azure-devops-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#prerequisites) your organization could emit. You could run it and check the support events.

```
https://auditservice.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/audit/actions
```